# Entity Framework 4.2 "The type is not attributed with EdmEntityTypeAttribute but is contained in an assembly attributed with EdmSchemaAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, repository

I am receiving the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled   Message=The type
>   'Judge' is not attributed with EdmEntityTypeAttribute but is contained
>   in an assembly attributed with EdmSchemaAttribute. POCO entities that
>   do not use EdmEntityTypeAttribute cannot be contained in the same
>   assembly as non-POCO entities that use EdmEntityTypeAttribute.
>   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type
>   entityType)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)....

```
 public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal z context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(z context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        this.context = new z();
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {

        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList(); //Getting error here!!
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The weird part is Judge is attributed with the EdmEntityTypeAttribute, because it is automatically generated as part of the DbContext T-4 jazz.

```
    /// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="standaloneModel", Name="Judge")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Judge : EntityObject
{
```

At one point I did have another class Judge in a different assembly, but I have since renamed it.  I have tried cleaning both projects.  There should be no other Judge class besides the EF one.

So I can not figure out where this other Judge class is coming from??

Thanks

Comment: Try deleting the bin and obj folders to ensure nothing survives.

Comment: Tried that, still getting the same error.

Comment: At my last job I used to get that error occasionally, but I can't for the life of me remember how I fixed it.  If this was an an answer I would mark it down myself for it's degree of unhelpfulness.

Comment: As a last ditch effort to make sure EVERYTHING is clean, try checking out all the code to a different folder from your source control and building it there.  Visual Studio has messed with me before in this area.

Comment: Nope, still throwing that error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out.

When I first started the program I was using an ObjectContext with the .edmx.

Then I read about EF 4.2 and decided to use DbContext.

The problem was my .edmx file was generating classes, as well as the DbContext T-4s.

The solution was to turn off code generation in the .edmx.

So now, only the DbContext T-4s are generating my POCO classes.

Hope this questions helps someone else in the future!

Comment: Now is future that you save my times ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - it seems that in some cases (for example, when using WCF Data Services 5.2.0), it's a problem to have code-first/DbContext classes in the same assembly as EDMX/model-first/generated classes.  For me, moving the DbContext classes into a separate assembly fixed the problem.

Note that I didn't have a problem with code-first + model-first in the same assembly when just accessing the DB.  But as soon as I added another layer (WCF Data Services) I ran into the EdmSchemaAttribute error.