# Type or Namespace not found error while referencing Entity Framework namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web

I have added a ADO.Net Entity Data Model in my website and named it `WebSocketModel`. Thus, all of its code has been generated inside the `name space WebSocketModel` inside the `App Code` folder.

But now I am unable to reference this `namespace`. I need to use the `context classes` created inside this `namespace` to fire `LINQ queries`.

I tried to reference the `namespace` through the `using WebSocketModel;` statement inside my web form but am getting the error

```
The type or namespace name 'WebSocketModel' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What is even more perplexing about this error is that whenever I type `using` intellisense automatically suggests the namespace `WebSocketModel`. However, later when I build my website, I get the aforementioned error.

Comment: Are your Context classes and Web Site code in different projects? if so make sure both of the target platforms are the same i.e. .Net 4.  I've seen this error when one project is targeted to `.Net 4` and the other to `.Net 4 Client Profile`.

Comment: what is the version of EF dll?

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt they are in the same project

Comment: @daryal its 1.0(1 Neutral)

Answer (score 1):

OK took a long time but finally resolved this issue...I just deleted the entity model and added it again. After doing so, I got a new error:

`The type 'PatientBPData' is not attributed with EdmEntityTypeAttribute but is contained in an assembly attributed with EdmSchemaAttribute. POCO entities that do not use EdmEntityTypeAttribute cannot be contained in the same assembly as non-POCO entities that use EdmEntityTypeAttribute.`

And to resolve this I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492654/entity-framework-4-2-the-type-is-not-attributed-with-edmentitytypeattribute-but) incredibly helpful

Comment: I just had the same issue when updating from Entity Framework 4 to EF6 in VS2013. I resolved it by deleting my edmx file and recreating.