# The type is not attributed with EdmEntityTypeAttribute but is contained in an assembly attributed with EdmSchemaAttribute

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting this error on one of the pages in my MVC4 app

```
The type 'Group' is not attributed with EdmEntityTypeAttribute but is 
contained in an assembly attributed with EdmSchemaAttribute. POCO 
entities that do not use EdmEntityTypeAttribute cannot be contained 
in the same assembly as non-POCO entities that use EdmEntityTypeAttribute.
```

One minute it was working fine, the next this error cropped up and won't go away. I haven't changed anything related to the Context Model. If I roll back all my other code changes, the error continues.

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492654/entity-framework-4-2-the-type-is-not-attributed-with-edmentitytypeattribute-but) post, which deals with a similar error. However I'm using DbContext throughout. The fix doesn't work for me.

I've tried regenerating the classes and even deleting and recreating the .edmx, nothing is working for me.

Here's a portion of code for one of the non-working classes

The table (SQL create statement lifted from SQL server):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Groups](
    [group_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [parent_group_id] [int] NULL,
    [group_type] [tinyint] NULL,
    [group_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [date_created] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [date_accessed] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [date_modified] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [date_deleted] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [n_total_contacts] [int] NULL,
    [n_unsubscribed] [int] NULL,
    [n_excluded] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Group] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [group_id] ASC
    )
    WITH 
    (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
    ) 
    ON [PRIMARY]
) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

The auto-generated context class:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Objects;
    using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext () : base("name=MyDbContext ")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The auto-generated Group.cs class:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Group
    {
        public int group_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> user_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> parent_group_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> group_type { get; set; }
        public string group_name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_created { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_accessed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_modified { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_deleted { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> n_total_contacts { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> n_unsubscribed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> n_excluded { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The View model:

```
public class GroupsListModel
{
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```
public ActionResult List() 
{
    GroupsListModel model = new GroupsListModel();
    using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        model.Groups = db.Groups.ToList();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Again, I'd just like to add that this was all working 15 minutes ago. I changed a few lines in my view which caused this error, and when I change it back the error remains.

**UPDATE: **

I've accepted @Pawel's answer below as it resolved the original issue, but I just wanted to share a bit more info on the full solution

In this project I have connections to two servers, one of which runs Sql Server 2005 and one which runs Sql Server 2008. After removing the EdmSchemaAttribute, I got a new error:

`All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken ’2008′ is different from ’2005′ that was encountered earlier.`

I googled and found suggestions that I should edit the 2005 .edmx file and change the 2005 to 2008. This resulted in a new error: `The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype ‘datetime2′`

So as it turns out, one of the `datetime` columns in my SQL Server 2008 DB was actually a `date` column. For everything else, this made no difference, but `date` maps to `datetime2` in EF, which caused a problem with the 2005 schema. I believe this maybe the root cause of the problem.

The solution I used was to edit my 2008 .edmx file, change the 2008 to 2005 and change the `date` field to a `datetime`. The project compiled and ran without issue after this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before EF supported POCO entities it only supported non-POCO entities. Non-POCO entities were derived from EntityObject class and each entity, complex type, enum type, member etc. had to be attributed with EF specific attributes or they would not work. The assembly where non-POCO entities lived had to be attributed with the `EdmSchemaAttribute`. If an assembly had this attribute EF knew it contained non-POCO attributes and looked only for those. POCO and non-POCO types could not live in the same assembly. In your case you seem to have the `EdmSchemaAttribute` defined somewhere in your project (note that this is an assembly level attribute so it can basically live in any file). If you want to use just POCO types just find the attribute and remove it. If you want to mix POCO and non-POCO types you need to define POCO types in a different assembly than non-POCO types are defined (I would not recommend mixing POCO and non-POCO types though).
Note that in the EF Designer non-POCO types used to be the default choice in the VS2010 (EntityObject based Entities and ObjectContext based context). In the designer that shipped with VS2012 the default context is DbContext but you still can change the Code Generation Strategy to "Default" (funnily the default Code Generation Strategy which creates DbContext based context and POCO entities is called "None"). If you do that then the code generated for the model will add the `EdmSchemAttribute`. In VS2013 (and the [OOB version for VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762)) if you are targeting EF6 you won't be able to select Code Generation Strategy (everything is T4 based - if you really needed ObjectContext you should be able to find templates on VS Gallery). If you are targeting EF5 however you will be able to choose the strategy to generate non-POCO stuff but I think is called something like Legacy ObjectContext as opposed to T4 which is DbContext and friends.

Comment: I found an `EdmSchemaAttribute` in a file and removed it. That solved the issue. However, another issue immediately popped up: `All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken ’2008′ is different from ’2005′ that was encountered earlier.` I have two databases connected to the app. One is 2005 and one is 2008. Again, this all worked fine two days ago - the issues suddenly started yesterday!

Comment: Update: Managed to fix that by setting the newer providers to 2005. I'm accepting this answer!